# C alternative to qDebug()

Tags: c, qt, printf

I have a QT application written in C++, but at one point it makes a call to a function in a C library.

I would like the C function to display to the output for debugging purposes. However `qDebug()` can't be called in C.

Is there an alternative to `qDebug()` that can be used in C? I've tried `printf()` but it doesn't seem to display anything.

```
printf("Test output");
```

IDE is QT Creator and I'd like the output to be displayed in the "Application Output" pane.

Comment: When you use printf(), does it work if you add a call to `fflush(stdout)` after it?

Comment: Could you make a wrapper for `qDebug()` that could be called from C?

Comment: @JarMan - yes it does, thanks for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After calling `printf`, add a call to `fflush(stdout)`. That should fix the problem.